# Pass the selected checkbox value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view like this:

```
@model SCWW.Areas.OnlineBookings.Models.Updates.UpdateDetailsModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Updates", new { area = "OnlineBookings", consignmentKey = Model.ConsignmentKey }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "updateableForm" }))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Updateable - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConsignmentKey)</legend>
    <div class="well well-small ">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ConsignmentKey)

        <table id="updateDetails" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Completed Date</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Apply)</td>
                    <td class="table-input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompletedDate, new { Disabled = "Disabled" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cancelled Date</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Apply)</td>
                    <td class="table-input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CancelDate, new { Disabled = "Disabled" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Booking Number</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Apply)</td>
                    <td class="table-input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookingNumber, new { Disabled = "Disabled" })</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" id="applyProxy" name="action" value="@FormAction.Apply" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

}

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Apply(UpdateDetailsModel model, FormAction action)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Submit",     GenerateViewModel(model.ConsignmentKey));
        }

        updateableService.Update(model.ConsignmentKey,"CompletedDate", model.ToDto());

        return RedirectToActionWithHash("Details", "otherActionsTab", "Bookings",
                                       new { consignmentKey = model.ConsignmentKey });
    }
```

In my view there 3 rows each with one checkbox. Only one checkbox is seleted when i click "update" button on View.
How would i get to know which checkbox is selected? How to pass the selected checkbox value from view to controller - Apply(UpdateDetailsModel model, FormAction action) in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same model property 3 times. You'll need to create separate properties for each condition.

Comment: is there an other way instead of using 3 separate properties? Please.

Comment: Nothing that is not ambiguous. You could guess based on which textbox has input in it, but that breaks as soon as the user puts input in > 1 textbox even if they only select one option. You need 3 properties for 3 choices.